# Installation failure - the mongodb driver for PHP on El Capitan

Tags: driver, php

I tried to install the mongodb driver for PHP on El Capitan. While running sudo pecl install mongo, I get the error message:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo

fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/evp.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [io_stream.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
PEAR Version: 1.9.4 PHP Version: 5.5.28
```

I tried mongo driver install with PHP 5.5.26 also.

Comment: What does the XAMPP documentation say? Where is ssl installed? Have you installed Xcode?

Comment: I installed xcode and open ssl also using brew. The problem started after I updated from yosemite to El Capitan. I tried this with default php MAMP and XAMPP.

Comment: Did you install ssl and Xcode after the OS upgrade? What files got moved from /usr?

Comment: Installed ssl after OS upgrade but Xcode is already there. I'm not sure abt the files as I recently moved to MAC :)

Comment: Just seen on another mailing list and I don't have El Capitan. El Capitan does not have OpenSSL so you would need to install that which was not needed for earlier OS X. or better get XMAMP to fix this or give instructions

Comment: What is XMAMP? OpenSSL i already installed.

Comment: and how did you install OpenSSL - that info should be in the questionTypo for XAMPP

Comment: used this command brew install openssl

Comment: Then XMAMP won't find it I assume it looks in /usr/include - you need to ask the XMAMP developers or use Homebrew to install PHP, MySQL etc. Don;'t mix packaging systems (unless you know what you are doing

Comment: Hmm I got it what are you saying. Let me try again.

Answer (score 1):

It should install the Openssl `brew install openssl` & `brew link openssl --force`

Using `xcode-select --install` to install commande line tools

It does work for me ^^

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Scott Wiersdorf seems to worked for me https://solitum.net/openssl-os-x-el-capitan-and-brew/

install opnessl through brew

```
brew install openssl
```

Link the openssl

```
$ cd /usr/local/include
$ ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl
```